# zend one controller many views

Tags: zend-framework

When I originally built my website, it was handling only one interface, but now I need to handle many interfaces.

I can detect which site to send for each request and isolate each site from the others, but all the sites have the same views.

Is there a way that I can render different views from the same controller?

I'm thinking something like:

```
application
            controller
            model
            site_1_view
            site_2_view
```

Is this possible?

Comment: This would get unmanageable very quickly. Can you give an example of the kinds of things that would be different for different sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very simple - I found that I could set the view base path in my constructor:

```
$this->view->setBasePath("../application/site_1_view/views");
```

So in `public/index.php`, I detect the URL, set it in the session, detect the name from my DB, then use the name to set the base path:

```
$this->view->setBasePath("../application/".$siteName."/views");
```

So the application structure is now:

```
 application
            controllers
            model
            site_1_view
                         views
                                scripts
                                         controllerName
                                                        ActionName 

            site_2_view
                         views
                                scripts
                                         controllerName
                                                        ActionName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->view->render('script.phtml');
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
public function myAction() 
{
    return $this->otherAction();
}

public function otherAction() 
{

}
```

Comment: steel i will redundant the actions between sites which is not my goal

Answer (score 0):

add a new scripts path to view
LIFO stack

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea: detect what site is currently being viewed, and then tell Zend_View to use scripts for that specific site by setting `$view->setScriptPath(/path/to/site1/scripts/);`

Edit: I might be wrong on this one, but the best place to set this would be a controller plugin in the `preDispatch` method, as at that time, you would know what module/controller/action has been requested, but not yet dispatched: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html